# Elastic Search weighted average aggs before version 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to get the weighted average of 2 fields in the elastic search, weighted average aggregation got introduced in ES v7.5, but i'm supposed to use a much older version (v5.x).

Can someone help me out to get the ES query for something like below in v5.x

```
sum of (grade X weight) / sum of weights

{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "weighted_grade": {
            "weighted_avg": {
                "value": {
                    "field": "grade"
                },
                "weight": {
                    "field": "weight"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.